# How do i fix this problem ive tried alot?

Tags: php, mysql

I run into an SQL query error.

The query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shoutbox` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NOT NULL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(6) DEFAULT NOT NULL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ' at line 5
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the problem: `syntax near '(6) DEFAULT  ..`.
how to fix: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version`.
So, what mysql server version do you have? `select version()` if have doubts.

Comment: Hey @danblack thank you for quick reply here is the info

Server-Typ: MySQL
Server Version: 5.5.62-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - 5.5.62

Comment: sorry you thought i was criticizing you. I wasnt. I should have been more clear. You can do a query thru a "prepared statement". It makes your query string less verbose and more precise. It also has the nice benefit of preventing sql injection attacks

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].  This link is also useful to get quick answers on SQL problems: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like your first import.

[MySQL reference manuals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/) are per the link. As you can see 5.5 is so old its in a PDF version only.

Since you are importing a sql file, look closer at the text of it, it will say what version it came from. The first step should be to install the same major version of mysql (the first two digits like 5.7 or 8.0). If the last digit is later than the origin sql that's fine.

Don't start with 5.5, its too old. Consider a minimum of 5.7 first or 8.0 if the version of the sql dump is later.

Comment: So i just need to Upgrade the Version am i right, is there a quick way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Default keyword should be before the default value

```
`time` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
```

assuming the posted code has been transcribed accurately this amendment fixes the posted error...
AND what's the point of not null AND a default?